# Tableau Target Vs. Actual - Can not get totals to show correctly

Tags: tableau-api

I am having trouble showing the correct totals in my tableau worksheet.

I have supervisors that are part of specific zones that need to complete a certain number of tests in different categories.  For example, supervisor 15716 must complete 8 tests in category 1.  I need to show the target, which is a number stored in the database and show the actual number of tests in that category that have been completed within a date range.  I have it working, but Im not sure if I did it correctly because I can not show any totals.

System target - number stored in database
CountOfSheetID - calculated field

[image]

Percent Compliant - calculated field

[image]

[image]

Comment: A LOD should help you here. https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm

Comment: I am using { FIXED [Test Officer SAPID], [Test Category ID] : SUM([System Target]) / SUM([CountOfSheetID]) }
but the percentage is not correct. The LOD is showing 69 for the first row, when it should 63

Comment: @Bob I also tried { fixed [Test Officer SAPID], [Test Category ID], [Category Desc], [System Target]: sum([System Target])   } but that is giving me 344 in the first row

Comment: What's the actual problem? You can't add grand totals? It doesn't aggregate?

Comment: FYI, your first calculation can be simplified to INT([Date] >= [MyStartDate] AND [Date] <= [LastSelectedDayOfMonth] AND NOT ISNULL([Sheet ID1])) easier to maintain - evaluates to 1 if the condition is true, 0 if not

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach -

First define a calculated field called [Within Date Range?] as

```
[Date] >= [MyStartDate] AND [Date] <= [LastSelectedDayOfMonth]
```

and put that new field on the filter shelf, only including data where [Within Date Range?] is True. (You could also just filter the [Date] field if that is flexible enough for you)

The you don't need the CountofSheetId calculated field at all. If you want to know how many records have a non-null value for [SheetID] within your date range, you can simply drop [SheetID] on a shelf and choose to treat it as Measure with the aggregation function COUNT()

Then just build your visualization to show the counts you want (not percentages, the actual counts)

Finally, you can convert counts into Percentages by clicking on the pills for your Measures and choosing Percentage under Quick Table Calcs. You'll want to experiment with the "Compute Using" setting to tell Tableau how to compute your percentages -- i.e. define percentage of "what".

Percentages are implemented as table calcs in Tableau. Read the help to understand table calcs, especially the description of partitioning and addressing.

Comment: thank you for the information.  The system target is dimension and I can not get the percentage of count(sheet id) is of the system target.

Comment: You can change how you use a field on the view from dimension to measure to attribute. It is perfectly reasonable to treat a field as a dimension on some worksheets and as a measure in others. To get percentages to calculate the way you like you have to set the compute using attribute to match your intent. Learn about table calcs from the online help. The effort to understand them will pay off

Comment: what ever I do, I can not get it to show the percentage or the overall percentage.  I have tried every calculation and everything else I can think of. I have it displaying system target and the count of sheet id, but can not get it to show what percent count of sheet id is compared to target

Comment: Publish a simplified example to Tableau public so people can see what you’re doing